# SetTimeout is not calling when tab is inactive OR API fails in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have scheduled SetTimeout to refresh the token in angular. My application will support multiple tabs. So there is a possibility of multiple refresh token API calls will be initiated at the same time while using multiple browser. On that case the one who is hitting the server first is getting success others are getting failed with

> 401 ERROR INVALID TOKEN.

So i did like if it is failed then  scheduled SetTimeout with 1 min delay. Since it is already token refreshed by another tab, after 1 min that it won't initiate one more API call.

Now the problem is, this process is stopping when tab is inactive OR when API returns 401 ERROR.

I want this process means interval check for token refresh should continue even if tab is inactive or if API fails.

Comment: What kind of authentication are you using? It seems you'll have to use localStorage to store the token and check that before refresh it, although most commons implementations to that for yourself.

Comment: Moving setTimeout/setInterval to a [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker) maintains it's interval and doesn't get killed as easily, but this method does have some smell to it.

Comment: Better to add code snippets of what you're doing here. Will help better understand the problem and give you a solution.